# i would like to open comments and comments input form in a modal popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my problem

where this button - link - php call:

```
    <a href="<?php bp_activity_comment_link(); ?>" class="fa fa-reply 
    acomment-reply bp-primary-action " id="acomment-comment-<?php 
    bp_activity_id(); ?>"><div class="comnekaj">Comment</div></a>
```

opens this form as a inline slide down:

```
    <form action="<?php bp_activity_comment_form_action(); ?>" method="post" 
    id="ac-form-<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>" class="ac-form"<?php 
    bp_activity_comment_form_nojs_display(); ?>>

    <?php bp_activity_comments(); ?>

    <div class="ac-reply-avatar"><?php bp_loggedin_user_avatar( 
    'width=70&height=70' ); ?></div>

    <div class="ac-reply-content">

    <div class="ac-textarea">

    <textarea id="ac-input-<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>" class="ac-input bp- 
    suggestions" name="ac_input_<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>"></textarea>

    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="ac_form_submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 
    'Comment', 'buddypress' ); ?>" /> &nbsp; <a href="#" class="ac-reply- 
    cancel"><?php _e( 'Cancel', 'buddypress' ); ?></a>

    <input type="hidden" name="comment_form_id" value="<?php 
    bp_activity_id(); ?>" />

    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'bp_activity_entry_comments' ); ?>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new_activity_comment', 
    '_wpnonce_new_activity_comment' ); ?>

    </form>
```

i am trying for more than a week now to display this inline form on the mentioned button click to show as a modal popup and am unable to succeed. 
       one of the problems i faced was how to sticky this on the bottom of the modal, to make it a bit more user friendly:

```
    <div class="ac-textarea">
    <textarea id="ac-input-<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>" class="ac-input bp- 
    suggestions" name="ac_input_<?php bp_activity_id(); ?>"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="ac_form_submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 
    'Comment', 'buddypress' ); ?>" /> &nbsp; <a href="#" class="ac-reply- 
    cancel"><?php _e( 'Cancel', 'buddypress' ); ?></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_form_id" value="<?php 
    bp_activity_id(); ?>" />
    </div>
```

on bottom of the modal...
Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

edit:

as per member request here is the html of the parts of the page i was talking about...

```
    <div class="activity-meta">
```

here is the link that opens the input text box and the comments:

```
    <a href="?ac=14688/#ac-form-14688" class="fa fa-reply acomment-reply bp- 
    primary-action " id="acomment-comment-14688"><div 
    class="com1">Comment</div></a>
```

and this is the form that should open in modal popup in this example it has comments....

```
    <div class="activity-comments">
```

and this form i would like to display as popup with

```
    <form action="https://test.com/.../reply/" method="post" id="ac-form-14688" 
    class="ac-form">
                <ul>

    <li id="acomment-14690">
    <div class="acomment-avatar">
    <a href="https://test.com/members/.../">
    <img src="https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/2347/5a32cc81b1bb9- 
    bpthumb.jpg" class="avatar user-2347-avatar avatar-50 photo" width="50" 
    height="50" alt="Profile picture of ..." />     </a>
    </div>

    <div class="acomment-meta">
    <a href="https://test.com/members/.../">...</a> replied <a 
    href="https://test.com/.../p/14688/#acomment-14690" class="activity-time- 
    since"><span class="time-since">15 hours, 15 minutes ago</span></a> </div>

    <div class="acomment-content"><p>I try and main line mine&#8230; </p>
    </div>

    <div class="acomment-options">


    <a href="#" class="bp-secondary-action buddyboss_edit_activity_comment" 
    onclick="return buddypress_edit_activity_initiate(this);" data- 
    activity_id="14690">
            Edit            </a>


    <a href="https://test.com/delete/14690/?cid=14690&amp;_wpnonce=2c0babed04" 
    class="delete acomment-delete confirm bp-secondary-action" 
    rel="nofollow">Delete</a>


    </div>

    </li>



    <li id="acomment-14691">
    <div class="acomment-avatar">
    <a href="https://test.com/members/,,,/">
        <img src="https://test.com/wp- 
    content/uploads/avatars/3604/5bf70260a4f3a-bpthumb.jpg" class="avatar user- 
    3604-avatar avatar-50 photo" width="50" height="50" alt="Profile picture of 
    ,,," />     </a>
    </div>

    <div class="acomment-meta">
    <a href="https://test.com/members/,,,/">,,,</a> replied <a 
    href="https://test.com/.../p/14688/#acomment-14691" class="activity-time- 
    since"><span class="time-since">15 hours, 12 minutes ago</span></a> </div>

    <div class="acomment-content"><p>Yes I done that  before is good 
    technique</p>
    </div>

    <div class="acomment-options">


    <a href="#" class="bp-secondary-action buddyboss_edit_activity_comment" 
    onclick="return buddypress_edit_activity_initiate(this);" data- 
    activity_id="14691">
            Edit            </a>


        <a href="https://test.com/delete/14691/? 
    cid=14691&amp;_wpnonce=2c0babed04" class="delete acomment-delete confirm 
    bp-secondary-action" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>


    </div>

    </li>
```

Comment: Can you show the final HTML instead of the PHP source? PHP is pretty much irrelevant to this question, which is mostly about CSS as far as I can see.

Comment: here is the html of the parts of the page i was talking about in my question...